# Macbook Pro won't boot into OSX (circle with line through it), but Windows works fine

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, macos

When I try to boot into OSX, after 30 seconds or so the Apple symbol is replaced by a circle with a line through it.  If I try single user mode, it stops at a certain point before booting entirely and says "waiting for root device."

However, I was able to successfully boot into OSX after trying five or so times.  Then, after running for a few minutes it froze up.  I've been able to repeat this a couple times, but 90% of the time it just shows the circle.

I do not believe this is a hardware problem because Windows works fine (I am typing this from Windows), but it doesn't scream "software problem" because it's intermittent.

Any advice?

---

**PS:** I replaced the stock hard drive last year with this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820171569

I found a blog post http://www.klein2.de/does-apple-drop-the-intel-x25-m-ssd-support-with-10-8-3/ that seems to describe my problem, but I doubt that it is for the same reason.  The screenshot with the black background is exactly what I see when I try to boot into single user mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brought it to the Apple store where they replaced the hard disk cable for free (possible thanks to Applecare). OSX works again.  This solution defies logic to me; I didn't think it could possibly be a hardware problem because Windows worked fine.

I am including the relevant parts of their problem writeup below:

```
Issue: Mac OS partition boots to a prohibitory symbol. 
Windows partition can run fine
Occurred after waking from sleep, computer froze completely 
Steps to Reproduce: Observed at bar 
MRI passes, third party memory 
Booted to 10.8 installer and internal drive did not mount 
Booted to storage diagnostics and no hard drive detected 
Proposed Resolution: Replace hard drive bracket, has third party drive, run storage diags after bracket and see if drive is recognized
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you should do is apply the latest firmware update to your SSD.  It sounds like a firmware issue to me. You can do this from Windows.  You can download the Sandisk app for that [here](http://mp3support.sandisk.com/SSD_toolkit/ssdtoolkit_installer.exe) (but I suggest you don't trust an exe download from a random internet stranger! Check it first).
This won't necessarily fix your issue, but at least you can illiminate that problem.

[This page](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/278075-about-still-waiting-for-root-device/) has some details that may help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response! There does appear to be a firmware update, but the installer insisted on creating a bootable USB, which my mac was then unable to find.  There was an option to create a bootable CD, but I could not find the .iso to burn.  I'm still stuck, but I'm bringing it to the Apple store tomorrow to see if they know what's going on.

Comment: What's so strange to me is that I haven't had an issue for a year and the issue didn't crop up immediately after a software update. It was working fine last night, I hadn't rebooted in a few weeks AFAIK, and then this morning when I woke it from sleep it froze and wouldn't boot OSX anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac model released in mid-2010 or later -- If your Mac has the latest firmware updates, it can access OS X Internet Recovery. If the local OS X Recovery system is missing, late-model Mac computers should automatically attempt to access OS X Internet Recovery.

You can also force a system to start up to OS X Internet Recovery by holding down Command-Option-R. This worked for me. When you do this, your Mac tries to re-download the OS X Recovery system from Apple servers. If successful, this process re-creates the local Recovery HD partition.

Reference:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313